# Converting coordinates from Google Maps using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have been sent a spreadsheet with coordinates that are linked to Google Maps, for example: [https://www.google.com/maps/place/53%C2%B018'27.0%22N+4%C2%B037'43.6%22W/@53.307487,-4.6309757,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d53.307487!4d-4.628787](https://www.google.com/maps/place/53%C2%B018%2727.0%22N+4%C2%B037%2743.6%22W/@53.307487,-4.6309757,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d53.307487!4d-4.628787)

When I have extracted the coordinates (53.307487, -4.628787 from the example above), saved them as a CSV, and added them to QGIS as a delimited text layer (over the OpenStreetMap) they appear somewhere off the east coast of Africa, and not in North Wales as they should!

I guess this is to do with the coordinate reference system I choose, but I do not know which is the correct one to use.

Can someone advise?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Use [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator.html) for your CSV.

Remember to leave the OSM basemap at [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.org/crs_3857/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator.html).

QGIS will [reproject them on the fly](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#basic-fa-on-the-fly-reprojection) to your canvas CRS.

Comment: Great.  Thank you